# AttributeError: type object 'Split' has no attribute 'Train'

Tags: python

I'm following a simple tutorial using Google colab.

```
(train_data,validation_data),test_data=tfds.load(name='imdb_reviews',
          split=((tfds.Split.Train.subsplit([6,4])),tfds.Split.Test),
          as_supervised=True)
```

After writing this code I'm getting the error as shown below:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-facc01319dcb> in <module>()


         1 (train_data,validation_data),test_data=tfds.load(name='imdb_reviews',
    ----> 2           split=((tfds.Split.Train.subsplit([6,4])),tfds.Split.Test),
          3           as_supervised=True)

AttributeError: type object 'Split' has no attribute 'Train'
```

Comment: What module/library are you using?

Comment: I think you need `tfds.Split.TRAIN.subsplit`, according to [this documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/datasets/splits#specifying_number_of_subsplits).

Comment: Thanks Igor Raush. But i am alreadu using tfds.Split.Train.subsplit. I am getting attribute error after using this.

Comment: Make sure to check for version compatibility.

Comment: I am using tensorflow 2.0 with google colab

Answer (score 6):

`.subsplit` was part of the deprecated API, so cannot be used anymore.

Instead you should use the new subsplit API: https://www.tensorflow.org/datasets/splits

```
ds1, ds2 = tfds.load(..., split=[ 'train[:50%]', 'train[50%:]'])
```

According the [issue 1998](https://github.com/tensorflow/datasets/issues/1998).